Weighted Average of Var/Covar Matrix
I have three different types of variance-covariance matrices derived from the same series of returns:

A simple variance-covariance matrix using ret.corr().
A variance-covariance matrix adjusted with a shock on the correlation.
A variance-covariance matrix calculated using the EWMA method, which places more weight on the most recent data.

I am considering combining these matrices to create a new variance-covariance matrix. My proposed method is to take a weighted average of the three matrices:
My idea was to do weighted average sum of all this matrix :
new_var_covar = w1 * var/covar1 + w2 * var/covar2 + w3 * var/covar3
I would like to know if this approach is mathematically sound or if there are any issues with it.
I'm not an engineer or obtained a degree in applied math. Be simple and detailed in your explanation please !

What is the goal of your exercise? To create a covariance matrix that best reflects the future covariance matrix? It seems to me that you are making computations for the sake of making computations. Is this weighted average sum of var-covar matrices literature-backed?

I’m using this approach to monitor the ex-ante volatility of my portfolio. By applying a sum product, I can allocate weights to emphasize certain factors, such as giving more importance to current values or adjusting for the variance-covariance matrix when all assets show an increase in their correlations.
My main concern is whether the formula I've mentioned is mathematically sound. Am I violating any fundamental properties in this process?

I don't think you are (violating any fundamental properties), but personally it just seems strange to me. Before creating my own var-covar matrix, I would try to read up on what are the different kinds of var-covar matrices being used in industry and academia.

I'm not sure what "mathematically sound" means. A weighted sum of positive definite matrices still is positive definite... But I'm puzzled - why is combining the original matrix with exponentially weighted moving average using some $\alpha$ better than just using EWMA with smaller $\alpha$? Likewise, why combine the original matrix with stressed correlations instead of just stressing the correlations less?

If weights reflect the importance you attribute to variance-covariance matrix of different methods, I don't think there is any problem. For example, if w3 is much greater than w1,w2, that means you consider the method 3 is more reliable than the two first methods.

@KaiSqDist Do you have any recommandations ?

@DimitriVulis I understand your point, but while lowering your lambda you don't capture the stress correlation. When lowering your correlation, you don't put more weights on current returns.
And I'm not a master in math to build a var/covar matrix that will capture everything, so I'm trying to do my best with what I understand.
If you have any recommandations, I would be pleased to follow them.
